# Passing driver/object to other page/class - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I cant pass the driver/object to next class/page and have same NullPointerException in first/beginning class.

**PageObject class - SearchResultsPage:**

```
public class SearchResultsPage extends BasePage{

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@data-original-title=\"Compare this Product\"]")
    List <WebElement> compareButton;

    @FindBy(partialLinkText = "Product Compare")
    WebElement urlComparePage;

    public SearchResultsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }   
    public void compareItems(){
        for(WebElement compareButtons: compareButton){
            compareButtons.click();
        }
    }

    public void goToComparePage(){
        urlComparePage.click();

    }
}
```

**PageObject class HomePage:**

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage{

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public String PAGE_TITLE = "Your Store";
    WebDriver driver;   
    @FindBy(className = "input-lg")
    WebElement inputSearch; 
    @FindBy(className = "btn-lg")
    WebElement searchButton;        

    public void isHomePage(){
        String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(pageTitle, PAGE_TITLE);
    }

    public void inputIntoSearch(){
        String itemName = "ipod";
        inputSearch.sendKeys(itemName);
    }

    public  SearchResultsPage clickSearchButton(){
        searchButton.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, SearchResultsPage.class);
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
public class MainPage {
    HomePage hp;
    TopNavigation topNav;
    ComparePage cp;
    SearchResultsPage srp;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.opencart.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    hp =  PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    topNav = PageFactory.initElements(driver, TopNavigation.class);
    cp = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ComparePage.class);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void checkIsHomePage(){
        hp.isHomePage();
    }

    @Test
    public void changeCurrency(){
        topNav.clickButtonChangeCurrency();
        topNav.setCurrency();
    }
    @Test
    public void searchProducts(){
        hp.inputIntoSearch();
        hp.clickSearchButton();
    }
    @Test
    public void addToCompare(){
        srp.compareItems();
    }
}
```

And I have 2 problem:

1.When I run test checkIsHomePage() - FAILS (NullPointerException)
and changeCurrency() PASS. I dont Know why first test is FAIL if thist 2 methods are in the same PageObiect class - HomePage. What is wrong?

2.When searchProduct method Pass I want to compare product using  addToCompare(), but I have no idea how use PageFactory.initelements to make test on - page with search results. How should I do this?

---------------------------------------UPDATED----------------------------
Ok, i foud the reason why it doesnt work. Its becouse of base class (BasePage). I made it and extended all classes with PageObjest, and with constructor and super(driver). When I deleted "extends" and "super" in PageObject classes and used (this.driver = driver) it is working now. But what i made with this base class that it didint work??

---------------------------------------------UPDATED-------------------------------
My BasePage is poor now:

```
public class BasePage {
 WebDriver driver;
 public BasePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that `HomePage` is clearly intended to defer to `BasePage` (though you also call it `MainPage` in the snippet): its constructor passes the `WebDriver` instance to super(), and yet it has its own `WebDriver driver` member variable that never gets set, and that will be null when `isHomePage()` is called. You should instead have used the `WebDriver` instance from the parent class and dropped the 'masking' declaration from the child class.

Comment: so I shoud only remove WebDriver driver: from PageObject classes?

Comment: You didn't post `BasePage` above (could you?), but you presumably want the `WebDriver driver` there, which you set in its constructor and nowhere else. Remove the instance from `HomePage` as I said. Then just use 'driver' in the individual page classes.

Comment: So I should remove WebDriver driver form homepage, but should I remove it from page object classes? 
I cant run now my test becouce website im testing not responding...

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing super class `BasePage`. I'm confused between `BasePage` and `MainPage`. Shouldn't the latter extend `BasePage`? There's nothing Selenium-ish about this, it's just Java + inheritance.

Comment: i updated my first post, there is basepage. Ok, I know that we are talking about java and inheritance, but im beginner in OOP and i just want to know how what i made wrog that it wasnt work witch this basepage

Comment: That's OK, got to start somewhere. Let's just think of BasePage as the 'holder' of the WebDriver. Home and SearchResults extend BasePage, fine; and in their constructors, passing the WebDriver up to BasePage to look after is also fine. The mistake is for Home or SearchResults to declare **their own** WebDriver instance, which never gets set. Remove them, and whenever a WebDriver is needed just refer to the one from BasePage, which won't be null.

Comment: Ok it wordks! Thanks!